# A genetic disorder that makes people look like an elephant and a whale

Tags: genetics, diseases

I want to know if the genetic syndrome I invented is logical or just a total fiction.

There are seven symptoms:

1. Gigantism;
2. Truncal obesity;
3. Alopecia universalis (the complete absence of hair all over the body);
4. Abnormally deep voice;
5. Inability to taste umami (or savory, if you want);
6. Dyspraxia (coordinal movement disorder);
7. Inability to sense itch.

This genetic syndrome is X-linked dominant (affects mainly females).

People affected by this genetic disease have a higher risk of asthma, type 2 diabetes, gestational diabetes, bone, breast, colorectal, skin, and liver cancers, and hypertension, and a lower risk of osteoporosis and amyotrophic lateral sclerosis. They are also more likely to be on the autistic spectrum, and they tend to have a higher visual I.Q., a lower verbal I.Q, and an average logical I.Q..

Here come the questions:

Would people with this disease be extremely poor climbers but excellent swimmers (like elephants and whales)?

Would they be more likely to have a herbivorous diet (in other words, to be vegetarians or vegans) (umami is found in meat)?

Could they become good rugby/NFL players?

What would be their average lifespan?

Comment: I don't think elephants and whales are "poor climbers" as much as just unfit for climbing. On account of being quite heavy. And in the case of whales, not even having any grappling appendage.

Comment: FWIW, if it's X-linked dominant, it will be about twice as common in women as men - so yes "mainly females" but not overwhelmingly so.

Comment: How much higher than the average human would their risk for the various diseases you listed be? 10% increase? 400% increase? This would greatly impact their quality of life and lifespan

Comment: Their risk of asthma is 50% higher than the average human, their risk of type 2 diabetes and gestational diabetes is 120% higher, their risk of hypertension is 300% higher, and their risk of bone, breast, colorectal, skin, and liver cancers is 80% higher.

Comment: Also, their risk of osteoporosis is 200% lower than the average human, and their risk of amyotrophic lateral sclerosis is 30% lower.

Answer (score 1):

What would be their average lifespan?

A few factors based on importance

1. heat, colder animals live longer
2. bigger animals live longer
3. herbivorous animals live longer

A few examples are horses, big and herbivorous but really hot high temperature... They rarely live more than 30 years or bears being carnivorous, big and cold, can live 30 to 50 years.

Most humans are small, cold and almost herbivorous ( every population and civilization ever existed had or has starch as the base of their diet, making up to 9/10 of the food consumed in the world, even Neanderthals and prehistoric sapiens show signs of an almost herbivorous diet, they were eating about 10 times more fiber than the modern american) so yeah that's why humans can easily live more than 70 years and sometimes up to 100 years or more. The only exception being carnivorous humans like the inuit or cannibals which usually have a hard time living past their 50s

This because human break factor 2, it seems that for bipedal animals, the smaller you are the less you live... Gravity sucks, tendetially as humans being only a few centimeters shorter makes you live a few years longer.

So your strange humans might expect the normal life expectancy of a giant, and most giants ever born on earth, and I mean giant humans didn't live that much.